# Using NASA's GIBS WMTS servers with Mapbox mgl-vector-source

Tags: mapbox

I try to render [https://gibs.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg4326/best/wmts.cgi?TIME=${date}&layer=VIIRS_NOAA20_Thermal_Anomalies_375m_All&tilematrixset=500m&Service=WMTS&Request=GetTile&Version=1.0.0&FORMAT=application%2Fvnd.mapbox-vector-tile&TileMatrix={z}&TileCol={x}&TileRow={y}](https://gibs.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg4326/best/wmts.cgi?TIME=$%7Bdate%7D&layer=VIIRS_NOAA20_Thermal_Anomalies_375m_All&tilematrixset=500m&Service=WMTS&Request=GetTile&Version=1.0.0&FORMAT=application%2Fvnd.mapbox-vector-tile&TileMatrix=%7Bz%7D&TileCol=%7Bx%7D&TileRow=%7By%7D) by Mapbox vector source **mgl-vector-source**. But when I implement it I get some shift in thermal anomalies data visualisation. I cant get along with it.

[image]

Comment: it looks like a projection mismatch but to be sure we need to see how you are loading the maps.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works